# Ajax-loaded-content changes element in document that called it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question about jquery and ajax

I have 2 html files and 1 js

index.html

```
<h1><div id="parent_header">This is parent header</div></h1>

<button id="my_button">Click here to load child.html</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

child.html

```
<button id="child_button">This button should change parent header</button> <p />
```

now, my_button from index.html open child.html and loads it into result div :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "child.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

successfully. Now I want that child_button from child.html change parent header in index.html. How to achieve that ajax-loaded-content changes something in document that called it? (not using iframe)

demo: http://www.lobart78.byethost24.com/ (not possible on jsfiddle)

Thank you

Comment: Add this to the success function 
    `$("#child_button").on("click",function() {
   ("#parent_header").text("Child changed this text");
 });` or have `$(document).on("click","child_button",function...` in the parent

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "child.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
            $("#child_button").on("click",function() { $("#parent_header").html("just changed for horror!"); });
        }
    });
});
});
```